# Format number with EUR Angular pipe

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

I need to format a number in this way:

```
10,00
1.000,67
1,78
```

(Integer part can have an undefined number of digits, while the decimal part must be equal to 2)

So suppose to do this html

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" [ngModel]="money| toNumber " name="money" required (ngModelChange)="money= $event"
```

I use this pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'toNumber'
})
export class ToNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number | string, locale?: string): string {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2
    }).format(Number(value));
  }
}
```

This pipe I have just used in another part of my code and it formats the number how I want, but in this case, when I put this pipe in my html code the input type number field is empty, I get this message:

> The specified value "4,00" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: You will not be able to convert string with **semi-colon** into a valid number. See the regular expression in error.

Comment: why dont you use `DecimalPipe` of angular ?

Comment: @selemmn decimal pipe is not work I need to have a "," for decimal part and "." for integer part

Answer (score 0):

as you can't parse string with semi-colon to number using `Number()`, an option you can do here is use `parseInt()` instead of `Number()`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'toNumber'
})
export class ToNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number | string, locale?: string): string {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2
    }).format(parseInt(value as string, 10));
  }
}
```

Comment: you code gives this error:   Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check again, you should add `value as string`,  because `parsInt` applies only strings, also I have added radix parameter 10, to avoid future bugs

Comment: The problem is not my pipe , it is the default pattern in input type number . Look the html code of my inputy: <input _ngcontent-c3="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" name="money" required="" step="0.01" type="number" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="money" ng-reflect-model="-5.000,00"> ---> the format is correct for me but the input is invalid because it violate the default pattern. I need a EUR pattern!

Comment: only thing I can suggest here is to use `type='text'` and with javaScrpit do not let users write other characters

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Angular CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) and override the french display.
You can do it this way : https://devblog.dymel.pl/2016/09/22/how-to-extend-angular2-pipe/
Then all you have to do is to replace spaces by dots :)